# Open an ios app during an incoming call

Tags: iphone, ios

When i receive an incoming call i want to open an app, query the local database and get the call details to be displayed in the app. Is it possible in iPhone? If yes, can someone suggest on how you can achieve it?

Comment: No. You can't change the behavior of receiving an incoming call.

Comment: Definitely No. I already tried it for my application. But It is not possible

Comment: you might have noticed in call centres as soon as one receives a call that particular customer's details will be displayed in the screen before you receive the call itself. something like that.

Comment: This is not Android. Imagine the potential to abuse such feature.

Comment: ok let's say after i receive the call i go to the background open my app and on clicking a particular button in the app is it possible to get the current call details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this. iOS apps cannot launch themselves without direct user interaction, and incoming calls suspend any apps that are already running.

Additionally, I personally find it very unlikely that Apple would enable this in future releases, as it would potentially interfere with the "actually using it as a phone" related aspects of the iPhone. :-)

Comment: ok let's say after i receive the call i go to the background open my app and on clicking a particular button in the app is it possible to get the current call details.

Comment: @Arun, read this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html

Comment: you can not mess up with user experience . And that's the base for app development with regard to apple.